# Crossing the bounds of an overflow:hidden wrapper

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-cycle

bit of a pickle here:

Got a large jquery.cycle carousel, the slides of which are div elements with loads of stuff inside of them.

Rough markup:

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="slide">slide content</div>
    <div class="slide">slide content</div>
    <div class="slide">slide content</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the "carousel" div has to have `orverflow:hidden;` set on it to prevent a few bugs, however I need some of the elements in certain slides to display drop-down lists on mouseover, when I do this, the drop-down goes beyond the bounds of the carousel wrapper and is cut off. My first instinct was to use `z-index`, but that didn't work.

Any ideas on how to "go beyond the bonds"?

Comment: You could append the dropdown directly to the body, get the position from the clicked element and apply it to the dropdown. Not a very pretty solution but, I'll post it if noone has better ideas.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that the plugin is not actually forcing overflow:hidden (just my habbit for graceful degradation). Took it off and all is fine.

Comment: Point being, it's impossible to cross the overflow:hidden bounds, if the object that wants to cross it is within the wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use position: absolute on the drop down, but I do not recommend that.

Try removing the overflow: hidden; and put a height and width on.

Answer (score 0):

you could go with position:absolute for that dropdown list, but it's ugly.

try losing overflow:hidden, and using overflow:visible instead, it's the most correct way to go in your case, donno though how easy or hard it would be.